# drawing bezier paths with cairo

Tags: c++, drawing, bezier, cairo

I need to draw a collection of Bezier paths with the help of **Cairo** in **C++**.
So far I can draw a single path.

But I need to draw many paths consisting of multiple bezier curves and lines.

I load collection of paths from the external dictionaty generated by python.
Here, for this minimal example I introduce a path by the variable `path0`.

It is a vector, consisting of 2 subvectors. The first one represents a bezier spline, while the second one is a simple straight line.

The first subvector naturally has 4 components, while the second one has just 2.

Here is the example of my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "cairo.h"
#include <string> 

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cairo_surface_t* surface;
    cairo_t* cr;

    surface = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, 1000, 1000);
    cr = cairo_create(surface);
    cairo_scale(cr, 1, 1);
    cairo_set_line_width(cr, 1);
    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 0);  

    // Here goes the svg-path. It is a bezier curve and unconnected line. 
    
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> path0 = { {{82.801,-204.48},{66.241,-204.48},{52.561,-214.56},{52.561,-235.44}},{{277.921,-192.24},{277.921,-173.5}} };
        
        // Here I put the initial point in the middle of the canvas. 

        double x0 = 300+path0[0][0][0];
        double y0 = 700+ path0[0][0][1];

        cairo_move_to(cr, x0, y0);

        // Parsing path
        for (int i = 0; i < path0.size(); i++) {
            if (path0[i].size() == 4) {
                cairo_rel_curve_to(cr, path0[i][1][0], path0[i][1][1], path0[i][2][0], path0[i][2][1], path0[i][3][0], path0[i][3][1]);
                cairo_stroke(cr);
            }
            if (path0[i].size() == 2) {
                cairo_rel_line_to(cr, symbol[0][i][1][0], symbol[0][i][1][1]);
                cairo_stroke(cr);
            }
        }
        cairo_surface_write_to_png(surface, "stroke.png");
        cairo_destroy(cr);
        cairo_surface_destroy(surface);

        return 0;

}
```

The point is it I see only one curve on the canvas. Probably, the second one is outside.
Could you help me to understand what I'm doing wrong?

Yaroslav.

Comment: Your example does not compile:`t.cpp:35:39: error: ‘symbol’ was not declared in this scope`

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify what you are expecting to see? With the following change, I get something like two lines, but I am not sure it is what you want to see.

```
--- t.cpp.orig  2020-10-13 17:00:12.404871474 +0200
+++ t.cpp   2020-10-13 17:04:20.573101739 +0200
@@ -29,13 +29,12 @@ int main(int argc, char* argv[])
         for (int i = 0; i < path0.size(); i++) {
             if (path0[i].size() == 4) {
                 cairo_rel_curve_to(cr, path0[i][1][0], path0[i][1][1], path0[i][2][0], path0[i][2][1], path0[i][3][0], path0[i][3][1]);
-                cairo_stroke(cr);
             }
             if (path0[i].size() == 2) {
-                cairo_rel_line_to(cr, symbol[0][i][1][0], symbol[0][i][1][1]);
-                cairo_stroke(cr);
+                cairo_rel_line_to(cr, path0[i][1][0], path0[i][1][1]);
             }
         }
+   cairo_stroke(cr);
         cairo_surface_write_to_png(surface, "stroke.png");
         cairo_destroy(cr);
         cairo_surface_destroy(surface);
```

Result is:
[image]

What happens in the above program is:

- First you call `cairo_move_to(cr, 382.8, 495.5)`. This decides where the following curve begins.
- Then there is call to `cairo_rel_curve_to()`. This adds a curve from the current point to something like `382.8+52.5, 495.5-235.4`. The other two points describe how the curve is bent.
- Next there is a call to `cairo_rel_line_to(cr, 277.9, -173.5);`.

  - In my version, this adds a line segment starting from the end of the curve.
  - In your version, the call to `cairo_stroke()` deleted the path. Since there is no current point, the line_to does not do anything (well, it sets the current point for following drawing commands).